# How to use in Nhibernate with QueryOver the Projections.SqlFunction for a mysql function that have not params?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I allready now how to use for any mysql function with parameters for example:
I succesfuly use the function Date(dateTimeValue) to get only the Date part.

But now i need to use the function in this way Date() or CurDate() the objective is get de MySql server
Current DateTime. 
But the Projections.SqlFunction("Date", NHibernateUtil.Date,Params coma separate) not have a overload that use the function paramless.

So my question is, how can i achieve this ? Projections.SqlFunction("Date", NHibernateUtil.Date)

Thanks in advance for you time.

I use C# and Nhibernate QueryOver

Comment: so far I see on the method signature params is optative, you could send none

Comment: yes, that is what i want to do but i don´t see how

Answer (score 1):

```
Projections.SqlFunction("Date", NHibernateUtil.Date)
```

which is equivalent to

```
Projections.SqlFunction("Date", NHibernateUtil.Date, new object[0])
```

**Update:** to create a no args function you need to create your own dialect

```
class MyDialect : NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect
{
    public MyDialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction("curdate", new NoArgSQLFunction("CurDate", NHibernateUtil.DateTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: thnaks, for you anwser but this code that you provide me, give a compilation error and when i use new IProjection[0] that is the sugestion of the compiler i got a exception error. Did yo try that code ?

Comment: SqlFunction does not translate directly to sql but uses the Functions declared in the dialect. You could check if there is a currentDate declared, otherwise create your own dialect, inherit mysqldialect and add the appropriate function in constructor

Comment: I had my own dialect, but the problem is the same. The only way that i see to call a mysql function is using: Projections.SqlFunction("Date", NHibernateUtil.Date, IProjection parameters) and i can´t find a way to call this function with no parameters